# Where is XDG_CONFIG_DIRS set?

Tags: desktop-environments, environment-variables, packaging

If my understanding is correct, Ubuntu and variants set `XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` to something like

```
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-$VARIANT:/etc/xdg
```

Then, package-provided system-wide configuration defaults in `/etc/xdg` can be partly overwritten eg. by packages like xubuntu-default-settings by installing configuration files in, say, `/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu`.

Where is `XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` set/extended?

What would be the best place to put a file containing something like

```
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS="/etc/xdg/xdg-mydefaults:$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS"
```

Some candidates are `/etc/profile.d` `/etc/environment.d` `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` `/etc/profile.d` `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d` `/etc/systemd/user.conf.d` but none of these seem to be used by ubuntu and variants for doing just this so which is the *right* choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's set in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/60x11-common_xdg_path` (from package `x11-common`):

```
DEFAULT_XDG_CONFIG_DIRS='/etc/xdg'
DEFAULT_XDG_DATA_DIRS='/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/'
if [ -n "$DESKTOP_SESSION" ]; then
  # readd default if was empty
  if [ -z "$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS" ]; then
    XDG_CONFIG_DIRS="$DEFAULT_XDG_CONFIG_DIRS"/xdg-"$DESKTOP_SESSION":"$DEFAULT_XDG_CONFIG_DIRS"
  elif [ -n "${XDG_CONFIG_DIRS##*$DEFAULT_XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/xdg-$DESKTOP_SESSION*}" ]; then
    XDG_CONFIG_DIRS="$DEFAULT_XDG_CONFIG_DIRS"/xdg-"$DESKTOP_SESSION":"$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS"
  fi
  export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
```

To add my own dirs I'd use something like `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/70-local-my-xdg-path`

Comment: Interesting. Basically the same code as in the file I pointed at (which is installed by `gnome-session-common`).

Comment: note that ${DESKTOP_SESSION} is something like 'ubuntu' or 'ubuntu-wayland'. On my system, I do not see a directory '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu'.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what's "right", but at least `/etc/profile.d` works fine for me.

```
$ cat /etc/profile.d/my-xdg-dir.sh
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS="/etc/xdg/xdg-mydefaults:$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS"

$ echo $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
/etc/xdg/xdg-mydefaults:/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
```

As regards your question where it's set, the `/etc/profile.d/xdg_dirs_desktop_session.sh` file looks suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu it was stored in `~/.xsessionrc`